# Maximum principle for proper subset of the boundary of positive measure (Rudin, Function Theory on the Unit Ball of $\mathbb C^n$)

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Suppose that $\phi$ is an holomorphic bounded function on the unit ball of $\mathbb C$, such that $\phi(re^{i\theta})$ tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to $1$ for $\theta$ in a positive-measure set $\subseteq[0,2\pi]$.

I have to prove that $\phi(z)=0 \forall z$. Can I apply some refined form of the maximum principle?

The problem is in Rudin, Function theory on the unit ball of $\mathbb C^n$, proof of Lemma 15.2.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Us Theorem 15.19. If $\phi$ is not identically 0, then the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|\phi(e^{it})|dt\geq |\log\phi(0)|$. In the inequality $\phi(e^{it})$ are really the radial limits of $\phi$. Therefore the left-hard side is not $-\infty$. But is the zero set of the boundary values has positive measure then that integral is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

In my copy of Rudin's Real and Complex analysis it is Theorem 15.19, and I think people call it Jensen's inequality.

> If $f$ is analytic in the unit disc, bounded and $f^*$ are its radial limits then $$\log|f(0)|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|f^*(e^{it})|dt$$ In particular, if the function is not identically zero then the right-hand side is not $-\infty$.

If $\phi$ is not identically 0, then the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log|\phi(e^{it})|dt\geq |\log\phi(0)|$. In the inequality $\phi(e^{it})$ are really the radial limits of $\phi$. Therefore the left-hard side is not $-\infty$. But is the zero set of the boundary values has positive measure then that integral is $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 15.19? Perhaps you are missing a "dot"?

Comment: @W.Rether Quoting a theorem number is probably not a good idea. Since my copy might be different from yours. Let me instead quote the content itself. It is called Jensen's inequality in some places.

Comment: Found: thank you very much. Rudin, however, doesn't prove, does he? I had to look at Titchmarsh. Any ideas of why Rudin doesn't even cite the inequality in the proof my theorem 15.2.3? Perhaps he was thinking to another proof of the fact?

Comment: @W.Rether In Rudin's Real and Complex analysis he does prove Jensen's inequality. The inequality is a direct consequence of Jensen's formula. This one relates the zeros and the value at the origin with the radial limits. It appears in the previous theorem in the same book.