# A holomorphic function which is zero only on a part of the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, maximum-principle

We have the following question :

> If $D$ denotes the unit ball in $\mathbb C$, then let $f : \bar D \to \mathbb C$ such that $f$ is continuous in $\bar D$ and analytic on $D$. If $f(e^{it}) = 0$ for all $0 < t < \frac \pi 2$ then $f \equiv 0$.

Yes, the idea must be maximum modulus theorem. But I don't see a candidate function : I think we must multiply $f$ with some holomorphic non-zero function so that the newly produced function $g$ is identically zero on the unit circle. But I am unable to cook up such a function to multiply with $f$.

I don't see any further tricks to this : the setting of being analytic on the interior and continuous on the closure is maximum modulus fodder, I would presume.

Comment: Multiply $f$ but a finite number of its rotations (looks like $5$ is enough) until the product is identically zero on all the boundary of the disc.

Comment: Oh! Let $g(z) = f(z) f(iz)f(-iz)f(-z)$?

Comment: That's all. Now that function must be zero on the whole disc.

Comment: Now I think we finish it like this : the regions in which each $f(-)$ is identically zero are four closed sets, at least one of which has non-empty interior. It follows  that this copy of $f$ is identically zero, and therefore $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Now see if instead of a whole arc one is given that it is zero on a set of positive length on the unit circle.

Comment: Yes a similar argument would apply with the number of copies of $f$ depending on the ratio of the length of the zero set to $2 \pi$.

Comment: No, not an arc, just positive length. Its interior might be empty, like a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), but on the unit circle.

Comment: Then I would be in trouble. I cannot go for an infinite product. But can I still produce, by finite multiplications, a $g$ which is not identically zero on the boundary, but rather on a dense set, if possible. If not, then I think this is troublesome.

Comment: this question is from a book?

Comment: Not really, it is from a competitive exam a few years ago. I do these for fun.

Comment: Your idea for $g(z)$ gets the job done, since it's zero on the boundary, except possibly at 4 points, but it must also be zero at those points by continuity.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you for confirming that. However, I have no clue about totoro's question i.e. what happens if $f$ is given to be zero on a set of finite length but empty interior, like the Fat Cantor set.

Comment: Ah! There's a trick that works for both. I will write up an answer.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Oops! Never mind. There was a fundamental flaw in my approach. I was going to use the fact that if an analytic function's zero set has a limit point in its (connected) domain of analyticity, then it is identically zero on that connected domain, but that doesn't apply, here. I'm not sure how I'd handle his question.

Comment: @totoro  We'll have to ask him!

Comment: I am pretty sure it has been asked here before, and it is a well known result due to F. and M. Riesz. (If a bounded analytic function on the disc has vanishing radial limits on a set of measure zero of the unit circle, then the function is zero.). If $f\neq 0$ you can assume that $f(0)\neq 0$, by composing with an automorphism of the disc. Then prove that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln|f(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \geq \ln|f(0)|$ ([Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula)). If $f$ vanishes on a set of positive measure in the circle, then the integral will be $-\infty$.

Comment: Maybe Rudin has it in his *Real and Complex Analysis* !? Hoffman's *Banach spaces of analytic functions* has it for sure.

Comment: Indeed, it has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2355120/551819).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Any one in this thread may now answer the question : I will accept it.

Comment: That includes you. If you answer it you both check if you understood, plus you get the points.

Comment: Good point. I think I will answer it, but right now I am more sleepy than the sleeping beauty, so I will do this tomorrow.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683915/42969.

Comment: @MartinR You can mark it as a duplicate, I will assist you. I actually forgot that I asked such questions. I've been so over the entire ODE /PDE topics recently that I almost forget that I used to study complex analysis! Having said that I did have the solution (ref. second comment) , but I didn't write it down.