# Prove that $ f(z) = 0 $ for all $ z \in \overline{D}(0,1) $.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the closed unit disk and holomorphic inside it,
such that $f(z) = 0$ for all $ z = \exp (it) $ with $0 ≤ t ≤ \pi/2 $. Prove that $ f(z) = 0 $ for
all $ z \in \overline{D}(0,1) $.

I have worked this exercise for absurdity, but it has not reached any conclusion. I would like to know a more sophisticated test, perhaps by a direct method.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is zero “only” on one quarter of the unit circle. The trick is to consider the function
$$
 g(z) = f(z)f(iz)f(-z)f(-iz) 
$$
which is zero on all of the unit circle, so that you can apply the maximum modulus function to $g$.

---

If you are familiar with the Schwarz reflection principle then you can also argue that $f$ can be continued analytically beyond the arc $\{e^{it} \mid 0 \le t \le \pi/2 \}$ and then apply the identity theorem.

Comment: Just to be sure, we get that because $g\equiv 0$ on the boundary then $max|g|=0$ and therefore $g\equiv0$ in all the unit circle and then $f\equiv0$ right?

Comment: @ronkurman Yes, exactly. If g is identically zero then one of four factors must be identically zero, and that means that f is identically zero.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @MartinR how would you analytically continue it to the entire circle? I can see how the reflection can give you the right part of the circle, but not all of it.

Answer (score -1):

It follows immediately by [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Comment: I think that the "immediately" is misleading here: there are examples of functions which are holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, non-zero in $\mathbb{D}$ and have infinite zeros in $\partial \mathbb{D}$