# $f$ constant on boundary implies $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

Prove of disprove: Let $f$ be a bounded holomorphic function on $\mathbb{D}$ and continous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Suppose that for a constant $0<\delta < 1/10, f(e^{i\theta}) = 1 + 2i$ for all $-\delta \pi < \theta < \delta \pi$. Then $f \equiv 1 + 2i$ on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$

I am not really sure what to do. I first thought of the maximum/minimum modulus principle and can prove the claim in the special case that $f(0) = 1 + 2i$. However, I don't know how to prove (or disprove) in the general case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684021/42969. A similar trick works here as well.

Comment: another way is just to take $f-1-2i$ and use Schwarz reflection across the arc in question and get an analytic function in its neighborhood, but then said analytic functions has an arc of zeroes, so is zero

Comment: Is it possible to just use analytic continuation as quoted in Shakarchi: "Suppose f is a holomorphic function in a region Ω that vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point in Ω. Then f is identically 0." One could conclude that on $\mathbb{D}$ that $f \equiv 1+2i$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and by continuity the result would follow?

Comment: @Azhao17 No. This won't work because we do not have analyticity on the circle

Comment: @Mike But you do have it on $\mathbb{D}$ right?

Comment: @Azhao17 Not necessarily. You only have it on the portion $-\delta \pi<\theta < \delta \pi$ of the boundary which is not good enough.

Comment: @Mike Ah right, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

A really non-elementary answer: It is known that functions $f\in H^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ (i.e. bounded holomorphic functions) have non-tangential limits almost everywhere ([Fatou's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_theorem)) and moreover, if the non-tangential limit is $0$ in a set of positive measure, then $f$ is identically zero.
Applying this to $f-(1+2i)$ yields the result immediately.

I am not saying this as a way of proving the result, I'm just saying this to point out that the claim is indeed true.