# Showing that $f$ is identically $0$ on $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question: Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function.  Suppose that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\theta$, $|\theta|<\epsilon$, and $\lim_{z\rightarrow e^{i\theta}}f(z)=0$.  Prove that $f$ is identically $0$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

My thoughts:  Well, honestly, I am quite stumped here.  I was thinking I could let $f$ be analytic in some other region (can I even do this?), say the lower half plane and suppose $\lim_{z\rightarrow x}f(z)=0$ whenever $-1\leq x\leq1$, by assumption.  Maybe then I could show that $f$ is identically $0$ on the bigger region, and then consider $f$ on the intersection of those two regions, and then ultimately making my way towards using the uniqueness theorem to show what I want... but I am quite stuck on how to do that... any thoughts, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: You can generalize the approach from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684021/42969.

Comment: **HINT** Assuming that $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc, what does $z\rightarrow e^{i\theta}$ mean geometrically? How can you use the fact that **all** values of theta have their absolute value bounded by some $\epsilon$?

Comment: hmmm... let's see here... @MathsWizzard, wouldn't $z\rightarrow e^{i\theta}$, mean that $z$ is approaching the boundary of the unit circle?  So, as $z$ approaches the boundary of the unit circle, $f(z)\rightarrow\infty$, right?  So, now if I consider the function $g$ that MartinR defined in the other problem, and then its the same as the comment from Ron Kurman in that problem.... right?  Or am I still missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that $f$ is analytic on the open unit disk $\mathbb D$, with $\lim_{z \to e^{i\theta}} f(z) = 0$ for $-\epsilon < \theta < \epsilon$.
Extend $f$ to an an analytic function on $A = \{z: |z| > 1\}$ by $f(z) = \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}$.  With $f(z) = 0$ for $z = e^{i\theta}$, $-\epsilon < \theta < \epsilon$, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb D \cup A \cup \{e^{i\theta}: -\epsilon < \theta < \epsilon\}$.  Using Morera's theorem, $f$ is analytic there.  But an analytic function whose zeros have a limit point in its domain is identically $0$.

Comment: Thank you!  One question: When you extended $f$ to an analytic function on $\{z:|z|>1\}$, you can only do that, because we know how $f$ behaves as $f$ approaches the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$, correct?

Comment: We can always get an analytic function on $A$ by $f(z) = \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}$.  It is only going to extend to be continuous (and therefore analytic, by Morera) on our segment of the circle when the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches a point on the boundary is real.

Comment: This is actually a version of the Schwarz reflection principle.