# If ()=0 for all those ∈ closure U with Re=1, show that  is the constant function zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let  be the square region
 ={∈ℂ:|Re|<1 and |Im|<1}.
Let :→ℂ be a continuous function which is holomorphic on .  If ()=0 for all those
∈ closure of U with Re=1, show that  is the constant function zero.

For this question, based on my knowledge, The theorem which may used to prove the f(z) is constant function either Liouville or Isolated zero theorem.

At this point, I don't know how to make use of the f(z) = 0 for all z belongs to closure of U. Can anyone give some Hint ?

Comment: What do you mean by “$f(z) = 0$ for all $z$ on the closure of $U$ with $\operatorname{Re} z= 1$? – $f$ is not even *defined* on the closure of $U$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ and continuous on the closure of $U$. Then have a look at this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683915/42969.

Comment: @MartinR sorry, I have not mentioned that the f is holomorphic on U and continuous on the closure of U. But what do you mean by f is not defined on closure of U ? since the question does not say that f is 0 for z in closure of U ?

Comment: You should say that $f: \overline U \to \Bbb C$ is a continuous function which is holomorphic in $U$ – But anyway, look at the question that I linked to, you can proceed in the same way as decribed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684021/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Moreover, thank you for the similar question you gave me to look at. You mentioned a principle called " Schwarz Reflection " which I learned recently. Can you give some explanation on it since I only know that it is a tools to extend the domain of holomorphic function. But I don't understand how to make use of it to help us doing the proof

Comment: Since $f$ is zero on the right side of the square $U$, you can extend the function $f$ to be holomorphic obtained by reflecting the square at that side, that is to the rectangle $-1 < \operatorname{Re} z < 3$, $-1 < \operatorname{Im} < 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Is it mean that I can reflect any side of U on the complex plane ?

Comment: @MartinR for question you gave me to look, why do we need to consider the function of g(z) in that form ?

Comment: Because $g$ is zero *everywhere* on the boundary of $U$, so that you can apply the maximum modulus principle to conclude that $g$ is identically zero.